# Files created in airflow task deleted automatically or not

Tags: airflow, mwaa

In my airflow task, I am creating a file using `open()` method in airflow dag and writing records into it. Then sending it with a mail within same task. Will it get deleted automatically or will exists into the dag?

```
filename = to_report_name(context)+'_'+currentNextRunTime.strftime('%m.%d.%Y_%H-%M')+'_'+currentNextRunTime.tzname()+'.'+extension.lower()
            with open(filename, "w+b") as file:
                file.write(download_response.content)
                print(file.name)
            send_report(context,file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file will not be deleted automaticly. The code you execute is pure Python if you want the file to be deleted once the operation is done then use [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module which gurentee the file will be deleted once it's closed. Example:

```
import tempfile, os
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as file:
    os.rename(file.name, '/tmp/my_custom_name.txt') # use this if you want to rename the file
    file.write(...)
```

Comment: this time i tried this, but getting exception as 
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpimudg_s1'**


`filename = to_report_name(context)+'_'+currentNextRunTime.strftime('%m.%d.%Y_%H-%M')+'_'+currentNextRunTime.tzname()+'.'+extension.lower()
            path='/tmp/'
            with NamedTemporaryFile() as file:
                os.rename(os.path.join(path, file.name), os.path.join(path, filename))
                file.write(download_response.content)
                print(file.name)
            send_report(context,file)`

Comment: refrence to the file only inside the block